# Dropdown select option shows price?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe I didn't constructed my question very good but I am trying to add to an HTML page a drop down menu and when an option is selected it should display some price and everything is fine by now, but when I add multiple dropdowns the price is showed only in the first div and I would like to make it show different price for each dropdown.

**JS :**

```
function changeddl($this){
   $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " $"):"");
};
```

**HTML :**

```
<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
  <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
</select>
<div id="divprice" class="price-style"></div>
```

This works fine but when I add one more:

```
<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
      <option>Size</option>
      <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
      <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
    </select>
    <div id="divprice" class="price-style"></div>
```

The price is showing in the first div and nothing appears to this one.
I can't figure out what should I change to make it work proper...

Comment: There seems no difference between 2 html snippets

Comment: Yes there is no difference but when I choose an option in the second dropdown the price is visibble only in the 1st one and nothing shows next to the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same `id` in the both lists when the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, else just the first one will be picked always.

I suggest the use of common classes, so try to replace the id `#divprice` by class `.divprice` example :

```
$($this).next('.divprice').text( $this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " $"):"" );
```

And HTML should be :

```
<select class="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
    <option>Size</option>
    <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
    <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
</select>
<div class="divprice" class="price-style"></div>

<select class="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
  <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
</select>
<div class="divprice" class="price-style"></div>
```

**NOTE :** Also the id `bedrooms` should be changed to be unique or common class as I did in the previous HTML code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not working at all...
check out this link: http://doormats.bg/ent-dm.php    scroll down abit and under the first image you will see a drop down, choose something and a price will appear after that scroll down abit more use the second drop down but a price won't appear it will only change the 1st price at the 1st dropdown.

Comment: Please check the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in your console first. then check my **NOTE** since you still have the same id **`bedrooms`** for the both lists.

Comment: check it again everything is set to your example and still not working

Comment: Ok, please replace `document.getElementById(".divprice").innerHTML = value;` by `$('.divprice').html(value)`.

Comment: now works fine, it shows the selected value, but once I change the second dropdown it changes all others to the current one and it's the same with the 1st one if I select something all other divprice are showing the current choosen....

Comment: Good, try now to use `$($this).next('.divprice').text( $this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " $"):"" );`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of `class` and `not id` since `ids must be unique` and the `.next()`  to change text of the next div
like

```js
function changeddl($this){
   $($this).next('.divprice').text($this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " $"):"");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
  <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
</select>
<div class="divprice" class="price-style"></div>

<select class="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
      <option>Size</option>
      <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
      <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
    </select>
    <div class="divprice" class="price-style"></div>
```

Comment: not working at all...
check out this link: http://doormats.bg/ent-dm.php    scroll down abit and under the first image you will see a drop down, choose something and a price will appear after that scroll down abit more use the second drop down but a price won't appear it will only change the 1st price at the 1st dropdown.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here but in my web site doesn't work

Comment: In your site i think you did not change the div id to class I can still see <div id="divprice"> instead of <div class="divprice">, similarly for the select dropdown, change that and it should work

Comment: check the page now, everything is like you showed me but it doesn't work... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
you need only one div to show value try this
<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option>Size</option>
  <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
  <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
</select>

<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
      <option>Size</option>
      <option value="160">90 x 50 | 4,75 kg.</option>
      <option value="240">100 х 200 | 7,35 kg.</option>
    </select>
<div id="divprice" class="price-style"></div>


<script>
function changeddl($this){
   $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("Price: " + $this.value + " $"):"");
};
```